# Get a line chart of Portfolio Value over Time by using historic data from a different table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

In the process of learning PowerBI, I'm building a small stock portfolio analyzing app.

**PBIX** - [Here](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/jRwdXkIr#link)

I want to make a line chart of my Portfolio Valuation over Time.

I've stock prices in the table `StockHistoricData1` on a day granularity. (If the data is missing, we should ignore that stock in calculating Portfolio Value)
Here is a small sample -

| StockQuoteTable | StartDate | EndDate | Date | series | OPEN | HIGH | LOW | PREV. CLOSE | ltp | close | vwap | 52W H | 52W L | VOLUME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VBL | 19-01-2023 | 18-01-2024 | 18-01-2024 | EQ | 1244 | 1249.55 | 1196.4 | 1248.5 | 1229.75 | 1230.15 | 1227.71 | 1747 | 755 | 1854390 |
| VBL | 19-01-2023 | 18-01-2024 | 17-01-2024 | EQ | 1256 | 1263.6 | 1230.1 | 1266.1 | 1249.25 | 1248.5 | 1244.89 | 1747 | 755 | 2159125 |
| VBL | 19-01-2023 | 18-01-2024 | 16-01-2024 | EQ | 1273.8 | 1276 | 1256.05 | 1271.7 | 1266 | 1266.1 | 1267.45 | 1747 | 755 | 1320740 |
| SBIN | 19-01-2023 | 18-01-2024 | 18-01-2024 | EQ | 625.8 | 633.45 | 619.05 | 626 | 628.5 | 628.3 | 627.46 | 660.4 | 499.35 | 14695436 |
| SBIN | 19-01-2023 | 18-01-2024 | 17-01-2024 | EQ | 624 | 636.8 | 623 | 636.9 | 626.45 | 626 | 628.6 | 660.4 | 499.35 | 30016308 |
| SBIN | 19-01-2023 | 18-01-2024 | 16-01-2024 | EQ | 640 | 644.9 | 633.45 | 640.1 | 637.55 | 636.9 | 639.72 | 660.4 | 499.35 | 15025543 |
| ADANIPORTS | 19-01-2023 | 18-01-2024 | 18-01-2024 | EQ | 1171.05 | 1184.3 | 1143.45 | 1166.85 | 1155 | 1154.05 | 1159.02 | 1229.9 | 395.1 | 5918594 |
| ADANIPORTS | 19-01-2023 | 18-01-2024 | 17-01-2024 | EQ | 1180 | 1204.7 | 1159.45 | 1193.35 | 1169.9 | 1166.85 | 1180.1 | 1229.9 | 395.1 | 5268593 |
| ADANIPORTS | 19-01-2023 | 18-01-2024 | 16-01-2024 | EQ | 1203.6 | 1212 | 1186.8 | 1203.1 | 1194.5 | 1193.35 | 1198.1 | 1229.9 | 395.1 | 3173587 |

I've my Current Trades which includes the Stocks I own in table `Tradebook_1`
Here is a sample -

| Symbol | ISIN | Trade Date | Exchange | Segment | Series | Trade Type | Auction | Quantity | Price | Trade ID | Order ID | Order Execution Time | CurrentPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IREDA | INE202E01016 | 17-01-2024 | BSE | EQ | B | buy | FALSE | 80 | 122.6 | 18654600 | 1.70547E+18 | 17-01-2024 13.27 | 122.7 |
| POLYCAB | INE455K01017 | 09-01-2024 | BSE | EQ | A | buy | FALSE | 2 | 4880 | 193925800 | 1.70479E+18 | 09-01-2024 15.25 | 4440 |
| IREDA | INE202E01016 | 28-12-2023 | BSE | EQ | B | sell | FALSE | 150 | 96.76 | 12881600 | 1.70374E+18 | 28-12-2023 11.00 | 122.7 |
| IREDA | INE202E01016 | 27-12-2023 | NSE | EQ | EQ | buy | FALSE | 50 | 99.75 | 27742304 | 1.1E+15 | 27-12-2023 15.16 | 122.7 |
| POLYCAB | INE455K01017 | 26-12-2023 | NSE | EQ | EQ | buy | FALSE | 2 | 5395.55 | 46925953 | 1.2E+15 | 26-12-2023 15.19 | 4440 |
| POLYCAB | INE455K01017 | 22-12-2023 | BSE | EQ | A | sell | FALSE | 3 | 5322.35 | 114766100 | 1.70323E+18 | 22-12-2023 13.44 | 4440 |

There are multiple `buy` and `sell` operations. Hence, Portfolio Value should increase and decrease accordingly.
**How does one go about creating a measure that queries price as per date in `StockHistoricData1` and calculates corresponding Portfolio value taking into account Trades done in `Tradebook`**

I tried using `RELATED` to get corresponding data by stock symbol but I failed when taking daily stock prices into account.

Comment: For simplification, take the running `Quantity' (with buy being positive, and sell being negative), and for each day get its day value * that running Quantity. Yes? Which value from historic to use (open, close, high, low) ?

Comment: Yes. That'll do it, I think. We have to use close value.

Comment: But we do have different stocks, they've different prices so a keeping a count on running total for each stock? Am I thinking this correct. Also, Price in Tradebook is the buy and sell price, and current price is the latest price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following Measures:

```
Cumlative Quantity = 
  var maxDate = MAX('DateTable'[Date])
  var cTbl = CALCULATETABLE('Tradebook_1', REMOVEFILTERS('DateTable'), 'Tradebook_1'[Trade Date] <= maxDate)
  var buys = CALCULATE(SUM('Tradebook_1'[Quantity]), cTbl, 'Tradebook_1'[Trade Type] = "buy")
  var sells = CALCULATE(SUM('Tradebook_1'[Quantity]), cTbl, 'Tradebook_1'[Trade Type] = "sell")
  return buys - sells
```

```
Portfolio Value = 
  var maxDate = MAX('DateTable'[Date])
  return
    CALCULATE(
      SUMX(
        'StockHistoricData1',
        (
          var thisSymbol = [StockQuoteTable]
          var thisPrice = [close]
          var thisQty = [Cumlative Quantity]('Tradebook_1'[Symbol] = thisSymbol)
          return thisPrice * thisQty
        )
      ),
      'StockHistoricData1'[Date] = maxDate
    )
```

Notes:

- In `Tradebook_1` you seem to be missing historic data. For example Symbol `VPRPL` has a net Qty of -160 (sold more than bought). So you will get negative portfolio value for this.

Comment: Yes, `Tradebook_1` is just a journal or trades done I need to lookup the daily process of those stocks just going by the Symbol and respective dates bought and sold.

Comment: I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: Truly Amazing to use a separate measure and call it to get the current Quantity! Thanks, Sam! This is a great way to bring modularity to DAX. Always learn something from your answers.

Comment: I'll see if I can tweak this to get a similar chart for Invested Value as well.

Comment: Hey Sam! With variable `cTbl` we're getting the entire Tradebook before the `MAX` Date in the current Filter context. So, it acts a way to only calculate buys and sells till that day? Another doubt, `var thisQty = [Cumlative Quantity]('Tradebook_1'[Symbol] = thisSymbol)` Can you please explain this syntax? Is this just a way to return a `TRUE/FALSE` by comparing current stock symbol?

Comment: `cTbl` get the dates before and including the selected date - this is needed to get all the past in/outs to give us the running qty.  `[measure](filter)` is just syntax short for `CALCULATE([measure], filter)`.